# How to filter feathersjs service

Tags: feathersjs

How to filter feathers Js services to publish real-time just on Chanel

```
service.on('created', (message, context) => {
console.log('message created');
return app.channel(`conversation-${message.ConversationId}`);
```

this code does not seem to filter the message to the conversation room desired

I read the discussion here: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/388
I can see the service.filter function was removed

Comment: Thank you, I added the correct code to my channel.js. The error was a typo. The channel name added in channel.ts was not the same when filtering the messages. User join (conversation/id) and was filtering for (conversation-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the standard [channels.js](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html#example) file you can see an example how filtering would work. First, the user has to be put into all conversation channel they are a part of on `app.on('login')`. Then you call [service.publish()](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html#service-publish-event-fn) *once* to register a publisher for the event:

```
service.on('publish', (message, context) => {
  console.log('message created');
  return app.channel(`conversation-${message.ConversationId}`);
});
```